# Wordpress Loop not finding any posts

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I have a wordpress page which includes 'The Loop' - when running the wordpress instance on my local server it displays the posts I have in my blog. When I upload it to a server this exact same code and database displays no posts.

I have simplified the loop as much as possible to make sure the code is not the issue.

I am out of ideas - any suggestions as to what could be causing this? PHP Configuration, Wordpress, Apache etc?

Comment: how did you upload the database? are you sure you have posts on this installation. You could check this on the bakcend (see haw many posts you have)

Comment: I uploaded the full database using sqlyog. If I login to the admin I see three posts. I can view individual posts, just not a list of them.

Comment: you could try with a base theme to put out the equation your code. Another thing to look is that the wordpress config for the homepage may point to a static page rather post list in some cases

Comment: just switched to the 2015 theme and I can see them. It must be the theme I'm using....back to the drawing board to work this one out! Thank you